# EverNote api call to local db

Tags: evernote

Can we use evernote apis to query the local device database - of evernote on android or ios devices ? I want to develop an app (or a plugin for evernote) which will work on the data that is stored in evernote. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

No, please use the API with Android or iOS SDKs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But what i want to ask is that - if we develop an ios or android app (using evernote sdk) - can we query the evernote device database to fetch the data that is stored in the evernote app in that device ?

Comment: I don't think so.